# Will accessing an image this way '127.0.0.1://src/image.jpg' work outside my computer? for example on github pages?

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack, and I have set the following rule to load my images, but keep failing to load it. ( I have installed file-loader as a dev depencendy)

```
rules: [
      // Other rules...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/', // Output directory for images
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

All my images have been created in dist/images folder. But I'm having trouble accessing them.

The only way I could accesss them, is if I change my src to '127.0.0.1://src/image.jpg'

Is this a reliable way to access my images?

Tried

- `webpack serve --open`
- Live Sever on `./dist/index.html`
- Install file-loader, url-loader and image-webpack-loader

Comment: How do you load images? What's the error? What do you expect?